# How to detect if browser is below IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browser-detection

I hate IE, I only want to display an out-of-date browser notification to IE8 IE7 IE6 IE5.5 etc. users on my site :)

I want to detect if browser version number is below IE8. I am open to Javascript, HTML, PHP, jQuery. How could I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this mark-up in your HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p>You aren't using a recent version of Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).